# How to override a function in a Javascript class, and call the base function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override a function in a Javascript class, and call it's base implementation?  I've achieved this by using prototypes, but I'm trying to preserve privacy for some of the data.

This is what I have so far, and it doesn't work.  I can see why it doesn't work, but I can't see a way to resolve it.  I'm beginning to wonder if this is not possible in javascript (without jumping through a lot of hoops).

Also, I need to support IE11, so can't use ES6.

```
    var NoProto = NoProto || {};

    NoProto.Shape = (function(){
        var thing = function(name){
            var privateData = 'this is a ' + name;

            var self = this;
            this.base = function(){
                return self;
            };

            this.doStuff = function(){
                return privateData;
            };
        };

        return thing;
    })();

    NoProto.Square = (function(){
        var thing = function(colour){
            NoProto.Shape.call(this, "square");

            this.doStuff = function(){
                // this fails (stack overflow)
                // ------> how to call the "base" function: doStuff, and preserve the private data?
                var val = this.base().doStuff();
                return val + ', which is '+ colour;
            };
        };

        thing.prototype = Object.create(NoProto.Shape.prototype);

        return thing;
    })();
```

Usage:

```
        var noProtoSqr = new NoProto.Square('blue');
        try {
            alert(noProtoSqr.doStuff()); // ---> Stack Overflow!
        } catch (e){
            console.error('There was an error: ' + e);
        }
```

For reference, this is how I got it working with prototypes:

```
    var Proto = Proto || {};

    Proto.Shape = (function(){
        var thing = function(name){
            this._pseudoPrivateData = 'this is a ' + name;
        };

        thing.prototype._pseudoPrivateData = '';
        thing.prototype.doStuff = function(){
            return this._pseudoPrivateData;
        };

        return thing;
    })();

    Proto.Square = (function(){
        var thing = function(colour){
            Proto.Shape.call(this, "square");
            this._colour = colour;
        };

        thing.prototype = Object.create(Proto.Shape.prototype);

        thing.prototype._colour = '';
        thing.prototype.doStuff = function(){
            var val = Proto.Shape.prototype.doStuff.call(this);
            return val + ', which is '+ this._colour;
        };

        return thing;
    })();
```

Usage:

```
        var protoSqr = new Proto.Square('blue');
        try {
            alert(protoSqr.doStuff());  // --> "this is a square, which is blue"
        } catch (e){
            console.error('There was an error: ' + e);
        }
```

Comment: The universal way is <original_func_reference>.apply(this, arguments) - To preserve context and pass all arguments. Usually, the return value of the original method should also be returned.

Comment: Thanks @AshwinGolani I think that's got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
NoProto.Shape.call(this, "square")
```

this assigns the `Shape`'s `doStuff` to the current instantiation, if that's what you want. So, now `this.doStuff` will reference the original `doStuff` function from `NoProto.shape`. If you want to overwrite the `doStuff` function on the current instantiation while being able to call the original `doStuff`, save a reference to the old `doStuff` before assigning to `this.doStuff`:

```
var thing = function(colour){
  NoProto.Shape.call(this, "square");
  const oldDoStuff = this.doStuff;
  this.doStuff = function(){
    var val = oldDoStuff();
    return val + ', which is '+ colour;
  };
};
```

Live snippet:

```js
var NoProto = NoProto || {};

NoProto.Shape = (function(){
  var thing = function(name){
    var privateData = 'this is a ' + name;

    var self = this;
    this.base = function(){
      return self;
    };

    this.doStuff = function(){
      return privateData;
    };
  };

  return thing;
})();

NoProto.Square = (function(){
  var thing = function(colour){
    NoProto.Shape.call(this, "square");
    const oldDoStuff = this.doStuff;
    this.doStuff = function(){
      var val = oldDoStuff();
      return val + ', which is '+ colour;
    };
  };

  thing.prototype = Object.create(NoProto.Shape.prototype);

  return thing;
})();

var noProtoSqr = new NoProto.Square('blue');
try {
  console.log(noProtoSqr.doStuff()); // ---> Stack Overflow!
} catch (e){
  console.error('There was an error: ' + e);
}
```